# Cell Reference in String Form Passed to a Range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I have dictionaries called rngsx1 ... rngy2 including cell range references. These cell references are passed into rangesx1 ... rangesy2. Because Array argument takes only in form of Array("A1:B2"), therefore i needed to pass them using Chr(34) which stands for quotation mark (").
I made for loop for multiple data strings in dictionaries. And i want to match their all first element with each other, all second element with each other and so on.
For the first trial i used only one element in the dictionaries and i wanted to print their values on a defined range.
But the subroutine doesn't work as i wish. Could you please help me on this please?

```
Sub CellReferenceToRange()

Dim rngx1, rngx2, rngy1, rngy2  As Range
Dim rangesx1, rangesx2, rangesy1, rangesy2  As Variant
    
' The Values at C15:C28 are assigned to rangesx1, rangesx2, rangesy1, rangesy2
    rangesx1 = Array("C15:C28")
    rangesy1 = Array("C15:C28")
    rangesx2 = Array("C15:C28")
    rangesy2 = Array("C15:C28")
    
' The Values at assigned ranges are set to rngx1, rngx2, rngy1, rngy2 
    For Each item in rangesx1, rangesx2, rangesy1, rangesy2
        Set rngx1 = Range(Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34)) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
        Set rngy1 = Range(Chr(34) & rangesy1 & Chr(34)) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
        Set rngx2 = Range(Chr(34) & rangesx2 & Chr(34)) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
        Set rngy2 = Range(Chr(34) & rangesy2 & Chr(34)) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"

' The Set Ranges are printed to the defined cell area.
Range("AD21:AG34") = rngx1 & rngx2 & rngy1 & rngy2
    Next
End Sub
```

When i rund the code, i get a Runtime Error 13 "Type Mismatch" which is on the line:

```
Set rngx1 = Range(Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34)) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
```

Comment: In the line `Set rg = Range("A1:A5")`, `rg` or `Range("A1:A5")` are range references (`... As Range`) while `A1:A5` is a range address (`... As String`). The dictionaries you're talking about are nowhere to be found in the code and it is unclear what their elements contain. When you do `rangesx1 = Array("C15:C28")`, `rangesx1` contains a one-element array with the string element `C15:C28`. To 'get' the value of this element you have to use `rangesx1(0)`, or more correctly `rangesx1(LBound(rangesx1))` as the first, or `rangesx1(UBound(rangesx1))` as the last element. Please clarify.

Comment: So please could you show me how to make a dictionary that contains range addresses and  put them into the set ranges through a for loop?

Comment: Where do you get the addresses from? You can have them written in a string, e.g. `Addresses = "C15:C28,D15:D28,F15:F28"` or is there another way you are getting them? Also, do you possibly mean an array instead of a dictionary (because you're using arrays in your code)?

Comment: @VBasic2008 So please could you show me how to make a dictionary or list or array or whatever you called that contains range addresses and  put them into the set ranges through a for loop? Because i have specific range addresses which contains values. As you can see there i have four ranges which are called rngx1, rngx2, rngy1, rngy2. I will put them into a xy chart, x1 and x2 for x values and y1 and y2 for  y values. Because i have multiple columns on my data table on excel sheet, i want to pair them in several ways in order  to compare the data relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Column Values

[image]

- Adjust the values (the worksheet names and the range addresses) in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumnValues()
    ' Make sure the addresses 'have' the same number of rows (cells),
    ' in this case 14 ('28 - 15 + 1 = 14', '34 - 21 + 1 = 14'.
    
    Const sAddressesList As String = "C15:C28,D15:D28,F15:F28,J15:J28"
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    Const dAddress As String = "AD21:AD34"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1" ' change if it is different
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sAddresses() As String: sAddresses = Split(sAddressesList, ",")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfrg As Range: Set dfrg = dws.Range(dAddress)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(sAddresses)
        Set srg = sws.Range(sAddresses(n))
        Set drg = dfrg.Offset(, n)
        drg.Value = srg.Value
        Debug.Print n + 1 & ".) Wrote values from '" _
            & sName & "!" & srg.Address(0, 0) & "' to '" _
            & dName & "!" & drg.Address(0, 0) & "'."
    Next n

    MsgBox "Column values copied.", vbInformation, "Copy Column Values"

End Sub
```

**The Result in the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)**

```
1.) Wrote values from 'Sheet1!C15:C28' to 'Sheet1!AD21:AD34'.
2.) Wrote values from 'Sheet1!D15:D28' to 'Sheet1!AE21:AE34'. 
3.) Wrote values from 'Sheet1!F15:F28' to 'Sheet1!AF21:AF34'.
4.) Wrote values from 'Sheet1!J15:J28' to 'Sheet1!AG21:AG34'.
```

Comment: Thank you very much @VBasic2008. I will adapt your code to my code. But your answer explains what i want. That's great job. As soon as i adapt my code, i will publish it here.

Comment: Can i use multiple addresses inside UBound, such as UBound(addresses1(n), addresses2(n)...adressessesn(n)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Frist `rangesx1 = Array("C15:C28")` needs not to be an array but a string.

```
Dim rangesx1 As String 
rangesx1 = "C15:C28"
```

and you don't need `Chr(34)` because `rangesx1` is already of type `String`

```
Set rngx1 = Range(rangesx1)
```

Also note that `Dim rngx1, rngx2, rngy1, rngy2  As Range` declares only `rngy2  As Range` but all the others are `Variant` by default. You need to specify a type for **every** variable:

```
Dim rngx1 As Range, rngx2 As Range, rngy1 As Range, rngy2 As Range
```

Finally `For Each item in rangesx1, rangesx2, rangesy1, rangesy2` does not work like that and actually it is not needed to loop here.

also `Range("AD21:AG34") = rngx1 & rngx2 & rngy1 & rngy2` cannot work because `rngx1` is the same as `Range("C15:C28").Value` so the value of a range is an array of values and you cannot concatenate arrays of values with `&`. It is very unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I applied your advice like answer 2.  Could you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like this:
But it is working. and giving the cell values inside the defined cells.

but i want to rangex1 extend to more ranges, like rangesx1 = "C15:C28", "C15:C28", "C15:C28", "C15:C28", "C15:C28", "D15:D28", "D15:D28", "F15:C28", "F15:C28"
Is it correct form to apply it? And can i iterate them in for loop?

```
Sub CellReferenceToRange()

Dim rngx1 As Range, rngx2 As Range, rngy1 As Range, rngy2  As Range
Dim rangesx1 As String, rangesx2 As String, rangesy1 As String, rangesy2  As String

' The Values at C15:C28 are assigned to rangesx1, rangesx2, rangesy1, rangesy2
    rangesx1 = "C15:C28"
    rangesy1 = "C15:C28"
    rangesx2 = "C15:C28"
    rangesy2 = "C15:C28"

' The Values at assigned ranges are set to rngx1, rngx2, rngy1, rngy2
    'For Each item in rangesx1, rangesy1, rangesx2, rangesy2
        Set rngx1 = Range(rangesx1) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
        Set rngy1 = Range(rangesy1) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
        Set rngx2 = Range(rangesx2) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"
        Set rngy2 = Range(rangesy2) ' Chr(34) & rangesx1 & Chr(34) ---> "C15:C28"

' The Set Ranges are printed to the defined cell area.
Range("AD21:AD34") = rngx1.Value
End Sub
```